# Working Matrix Square root

Tags: algorithm, matrix, math

I'm trying to take the square root of a matrix. That is find the matrix `B` so `B*B=A`. None of the methods I've found around gives a working result.

First I found this formula on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Computation_by_Denman.E2.80.93Beavers_square_root_iteration):

Set `Y_0 = A` and `Z_0 = I` then the iteration:

`Y_{k+1} = .5*(Y_k + Z_k^{-1}),`

`Z_{k+1} = .5*(Z_k + Y_k^{-1}).`

Then `Y` should converge to `B`.

However implementing the algorithm in python (using numpy for inverse matrices), gave me rubbish results:

```
>>> def denbev(Y,Z,n):
    if n == 0: return Y,Z
    return denbev(.5*(Y+Z**-1), .5*(Z+Y**-1), n-1)

>>> denbev(matrix('1,2;3,4'), matrix('1,0;0,1'), 3)[0]**2
matrix([[ 1.31969074,  1.85986159],
        [ 2.78979239,  4.10948313]])

>>> denbev(matrix('1,2;3,4'), matrix('1,0;0,1'), 100)[0]**2
matrix([[ 1.44409972,  1.79685675],
        [ 2.69528512,  4.13938485]])
```

As you can see, iterating 100 times, gives *worse* results than iterating three times, and none of the results get within a 40% error margin.

Then I tried the scipy sqrtm method, but that was even worse:

```
>>> scipy.linalg.sqrtm(matrix('1,2;3,4'))**2
array([[ 0.09090909+0.51425948j,  0.60606061-0.34283965j],
       [ 1.36363636-0.77138922j,  3.09090909+0.51425948j]])

>>> scipy.linalg.sqrtm(matrix('1,2;3,4')**2)
array([[ 1.56669890+0.j,  1.74077656+0.j],
       [ 2.61116484+0.j,  4.17786374+0.j]])
```

I don't know a lot about matrix square rooting, but I figure there must be algorithms that perform better than the above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(1) the square root of the matrix [1,2;3,4] should give something complex, as the eigenvalues of that matrix are negative.  SO your solution can't be correct to begin with.

(2) linalg.sqrtm returns an array, NOT a matrix.  Hence, using `*` to multiply them is not a good idea.  In your case, the solutions is thus correct, but you're not seeing it.

**edit** try the following, you'll see it's correct:

```
asmatrix(scipy.linalg.sqrtm(matrix('1,2;3,4')))**2
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly. Only I still don't see why `sqrtm(matrix('1,2;3,4')**2)` doesn't work?

Comment: It does work...  try squaring the solution, see http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sqrtm.html

Comment: Right, there are plenty of solutions, and sqrtm simply chooses another one than me.

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix [1 2; 3 4] isn't positive so there is no solution to the problem in the domain of real matrices.

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of the matrix square root that you're doing? I suspect a practical application the matrix really could be symmetric positive definite (e.g. covariance) so you shouldn't encounter complex numbers.

In that case you can compute a cholesky decomposition, like a scaled LU factorization, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

Another practical example is if your matrices are rotations, then you can first decompose with matrix log and just divide by 2 in the log space, then go back to rotation with matrix exponent... in any event it sounds strange that you ask for a 'generic matrix square root', you probably want to understand the specific application in more depth.